# "Quassopra" vs. "qua sopra": entrambe corrette?

Tags: spelling

So che "qua sopra" è corretto (almeno credo), ma mi chiedevo se "quassopra" (modellato su "quassù") fosse anch'esso una forma corretta. Online non mi pare di trovare niente che dica che questa è una forma corretta, anche se viene usata su alcuni risultati di ricerca Google. Quindi voi che mi dite?

Comment: È costruito regolarmente, con tanto di raddoppiamento sintattico. Non vedo motivi per considerarlo scorretto, seppure non molto usato. È l'uso che governa, non la grammatica: se lo scrivi molti lettori ne saranno sorpresi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma in un unico termine "quassopra" sembra essere  rara e perlopiù letteraria secondo quanto risulta da Google Books. Il termine non risulta presente in nessun dizionario. Personalmente la eviterei.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=qua%20sopra%2Cquassopra&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cqua%20sopra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquassopra%3B%2Cc0) qua sopra vs quassopra.

L'espressione non risulta presente nella lista fornita dall'[Accademia della  Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/unite-separate):

> - Dubbi relativi alla scrittura unita o separata di congiunzioni, avverbi, locuzioni avverbiali e preposizionali di alta frequenza.

Comment: Completamente d'accordo: non è riportata in nessuna fonte lessicografica o letteraria e, per quel che vale, non l'ho mai vista e mi farebbe un effetto parecchio strano vederla.

Answer (score 0):

In Italiano fino ad ora mai letta o sentita, concordo con le altre risposte.

L'unico posto in cui non mi sarei meravigliato a leggere simili forme sarebbe in qualche poesia modernista.

Questo detto, dopo aver letto la tua domanda, ho fatto una ricerca su Google, che riporta 1230 risultati. E sono anche rimasto sorpreso dal report su Ngram proposto da [xxxxxx](https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/519/xxxxxx), in tutta onestà mi sarei aspettato una frequenza minore.

Mi chiedo se ci possa essere una qualche influenza da parte delle altre lingue italiche, e.g. in Siciliano forme come accassupra, assupra, drassupra, accassutta, assutta, drassutta, accastabbanna, astabbanna, drastabbanna, sono perfettamente usuali, immagino che un madrelingua siciliano potrebbe magari trovare non innaturale tradurre e trascrivere accassupra in quassopra.

Comment: Non pensò sia dovuto all'influenza di termini dialettali. Probablilnente  "quassopra" viene a volte usato  per  analogia con il terminine più comune  e corretto "quassù".